# how to get multiple driving route results for single destination from google api call?

Tags: distance

I'm sending a curl call to the google API to get the driving distance between two points. But, it's giving me the shortest driving time route, NOT the shortest driving distance route which is what I'm looking for. When I do the call in a browser with google maps, plugging in the lats and longs, I get 3 different routes. The second route is the one I'm looking for, but the API call only returns the first which is longer in distance but shorter in time.

I see in the API documentation there is a parameter called 'alternatives' but it does not seem to have any effect on my call. Here is the URL I'm calling:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=46.839382,-100.771373&destinations=46.791115,-100.763650&sensor=false&alternatives=true&units=imperial

Answer (score 2):

ok figured it out.   the problem is i need to use the directions api, NOT the distance matrix api.  and then parse out the shortest distance.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.839382,-100.771373&destination=46.791115,-100.763650&units=imperial&alternatives=true&sensor=false